# Current sensor for sensing 6 mA DC & 30 mA AC current

Tags: current-measurement, hall-effect, current-sensing

I want to sense very low currents for both AC & DC for an EV charger application. General AC & DC sensors do not have that much range to sense the current. Please suggest some good component to use, preferably manufactured in India.

Answer (score 1):

A 10 Ω resistor will produce an output of 60 mV DC and 300 mV AC in your scenario. I think India makes those.